# Minecraft: I Can't Create an Account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am attempting to create a Minecraft account. On youtube, I have seen the account creation screen. However, when I click the register link, I am redirected to the Mojang website and I have no option to change my screen name. How can I create an account if I can't get to the normal register screen?

Comment: Since you've made it clear that you're trying to get around having to buy Minecraft, and piracy is very much off-topic on Arqade, I have voted to close your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registration has changed since Minecraft was first released. You no longer get a Minecraft account. Instead, you register a Mojang account using your email address. Once you have a Mojang account and have paid to make it a premium account, you will have the ability to choose a screen name and log into Minecraft with your Mojang account.

Comment: I have a Mojang account. How do I change my screen name?

Comment: I know I'm a noob, but if you help me I will mark this as answer.

Comment: @user1919496: Have you bought the game?  The indications I'm getting from the help pages is you register your screen name when you buy the game.

Comment: @MBraedley is correct,confirmed since I myself bought Minecraft about a month ago.

Comment: So is there no way to get a username without a purchase? If so, how can I set up Mineshafter for free?

Comment: @user1919496: You're going to want to stop right there before you get yourself in trouble with the community.  We do not condone piracy of any sort.  Even if that isn't your intention, the mere appearance of piracy makes some of us a bit twitchy.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm very sorry, I have literally just joined this site and had no idea of this.

Comment: @user The screen name *is* what you're buying when you pay.